# Reactjs project deployed to AWS S3 Bucket not loading assets (scripts, images, etc)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Situation**
I've recently encountered some trouble hosting a react project on a AWS S3 Bucket with the static website settings turned on.

I followed a few online guides on how to build a react project and upload all the objects to the S3 Bucket. I've enabled static website hosting in the bucket properties and set the index and error document to index.html.

**The problem**

When I access the project at the provided bucket website endpoint, the site attempts to load script and image files relative to that website endpoint which is different to the direct object URL in the bucket. Example,

Website is located at http://example.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, however, the page tries to load the index and vendor react scripts from http://example.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/index.js and http://example.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/vendor.js respectively.

I cannot load http://example.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/vendor.js from the browser directly **BUT** I can access the file at https://example.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/vendor.js directly which is the Object URL provided in the console.

**Temporary Fix**
In order to get the project working, I have had to manually replace all links to assets in the project to the Object URL from the S3 Console which has been tedious.

I have set the bucket policy to allow access to objects but I'm surely missing something because I can't figure out why the index.html can't access assets while being served by the bucket website endpoint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**
Screenshots of bucket:

[Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru9TU.png)

[Static website hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3JxH.png)

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGvA2.png)

Comment: can you confirm did you follow steps like this tutorial https://blog.cloudthat.com/step-by-step-guide-to-deploy-reactjs-app-on-aws-s3/
because. I have tried this and it works for me.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra that was one of the guides I followed - I'm very perplexed by this

Comment: did you upload the contents of build folder or the build folder itself?

Comment: contents, so index.html at the root of the project.

Comment: is it possible for you to add the image of your bucket and are you sure you not using any custom script?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra happy to do whatever, how do I create an image of the bucket? No custom scripts. The only thing I could think might cause this is a bad webpack config but in my mind it makes sense for the browser to attempt to get a script with the same web path as the html file.

Comment: by image i meant screenshot of the files

Comment: I think your build is somewhat odd, files are different form the usual react project for example images directory. How about you try to deploy default react app -> build -> upload.
make sure your build directory files are similar and same to the tutorial image files i have posted.